# Java FOR iterarions

Tags: java, for-loop, boolean

I was performing some tests in a program I'm making right now and I came across the following situation. Summarizing I'll put the following:

```
class ForTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException{

        int i;

        System.out.println("Press S to stop.");

        for(i = 0; (char) System.in.read() != 'S'; i++) 
            System.out.println("Pass #" + i);

    }
}
```

the output is:

```
Press S to stop.
g
Pass #0
Pass #1
2
Pass #2
Pass #3
4
Pass #4
Pass #5
5
Pass #6
Pass #7
S
```

In theory it should iterate one by one each time I type a wrong char but it perform the sysout twice. I'm curious why does this for statement behave like this.

Regards!

Comment: Newline is a character. `g\n` is two characters.

Comment: The question I linked above uses `Scanner.nextLine()` instead of `System.in.read()`, but the underlying problem is the same. Check out the answers to see if you can adapt them for your situation.